# qv and qp relationship

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there any relationship between q at constant volume and q at constant pressure that I could derive with just the reaction equation, and the enthalpy of formation and Cp of the products and reactants?

I am aware that q at constant pressure is enthalpy of formation of products - enthalpy of formation of reactants.

Comment: You are assuming constant temperature, right?

Comment: I had not assumed that but I believe we would have to as one of our state variables.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the initial and final temperatures in both the isobaric and isochoric processes are same. We will limit this discussion to ideal gases only. To calculate heat transfered we will use the expression $$q = nC\Delta T$$ Here C is molar heat capacity of the gas. For isobaric process, this will be $$q_p = nC_p\Delta T$$ For the isochoric process $$q_v=nC_v\Delta T$$
$\Delta T$ for both these processes same. Substracting these two equations we get $$q_p - q_v = n(C_p - C_v)\Delta T$$ The value of $C_p - C_v$ is $R$. Therefore $$q_p - q_v = nR\Delta T$$

Comment: No, there are some issues. Firstly, you should use $C_{p,m}$ and $C_{v,m}$ which are the *molar* heat capacities at constant pressure and volume. Secondly, the equation $C_{p,m} - C_{v,m} = R$ is only true for an ideal gas. If you want to limit the scope to just ideal gases, that's fine, but you should make it clear. My biggest confusion, however, if you heat an ideal gas at constant pressure, its volume is going to *increase*. How can you then have a *constant-volume* process that has the same initial and final state...?

Comment: Alright i will make the edits. About your confusion, you made a valid point. I considered here that only initial and final temperature are same for both processes. So if you heat an ideal gas isobarically and heat the same gas isochorically in two similar containers raising the temperature of both gases by a same amount, then my equation gives the relation between the heat required for both the cases.

Comment: Ah, well, OK. Then I suggest also changing "initial and final state variables" to "initial and final temperature", since "state variables" include $p$ and $V$, too.

Comment: Yes I've done that.

Comment: I don't think op was asking for derivation of mayers relation

Comment: @Buraian How is thia derivation of Mayer's relation. In fact I used Mayer's relation to derive the equation in consideration.

Comment: I misread, good answer!